# zlib inflate returning Z_BUF_ERROR

Tags: android, zlib

I am receiving a stream from android client which is compressed using `standard zlib` (linked against -lz). The following way when trying to inflate it, i get `Z_BUF_ERROR` error

```
if(!rawData)
    rawData= (char *)malloc(480 * 800 * 8);
int bufferLength = 128 * 1024;
char *tmpbuffer = malloc(bufferLength);
zUnzip.next_in = (Bytef *)inputStream;
zUnzip.avail_in = size;
zUnzip.next_out = (Bytef *)tmpbuffer; //output location of uncompressed stream
zUnzip.avail_out = bufferLength; //total size of output buffer
zUnzip.data_type = Z_BINARY;

inflateResult = inflateInit( &zUnzip); //standard zlib function, see <zlib.h>
if ( inflateResult != Z_OK ) {
    LOGE("inflateInit returned error: %d, msg: %s\n",inflateResult,zUnzip.msg);
}

do{
    inflateResult = inflate( &zUnzip, Z_SYNC_FLUSH );
    LOGE("avail_out = %d : difference = %d",zUnzip.avail_out,bufferLength-zUnzip.avail_out);
    memcpy(rawData,tmpbuffer,bufferLength);
    rawData+=bufferLength;
    zUnzip.next_out = (Bytef *)tmpbuffer; //output location of uncompressed stream
    zUnzip.avail_out = bufferLength; //total size of output buffer

}while(( inflateResult == Z_STREAM_END )) ;

if ( inflateResult < 0 ) {
        LOGE("zlib inflate returned error: %d, msg: %s\n",inflateResult,zUnzip.msg);
        return FALSE;
    }
```

The logcat output for an `inputStream` of size 16741 bytes

```
04-03 07:32:01.900: E/sc_client(25100): avail_out = 0 : difference = 131072
04-03 07:32:01.900: E/sc_client(25100): avail_out = 0 : difference = 131072
04-03 07:32:01.905: E/sc_client(25100): avail_out = 45672 : difference = 85400
04-03 07:32:01.905: E/sc_client(25100): avail_out = 131072 : difference = 0
04-03 07:32:01.905: E/sc_client(25100): zlib inflate returned error: -5, msg: (null)
```

---

NOTE: The input stream is `raw compressed stream`(direct output from zlib deflate call)!

## Update: deflate part

```
rfbBool zrleOutStreamFlush(zrleOutStream *os){
  os->zs.next_in = os->in.start;
  os->zs.avail_in = ZRLE_BUFFER_LENGTH (&os->in);

  while (os->zs.avail_in != 0) {
    do {
      int ret;
      os->zs.next_out = os->out.ptr;
      os->zs.avail_out = os->out.end - os->out.ptr;


      if ((ret = deflate(&os->zs, Z_SYNC_FLUSH)) != Z_OK) {
        Log("zrleOutStreamFlush: deflate failed with error code %d\n", ret);
        return FALSE;
      }

      os->out.ptr = os->zs.next_out;
    } while (os->zs.avail_out == 0);
  }

  os->in.ptr = os->in.start;
  LOGE("zrleOutStreamFlush: total_in %ld : total_out %ld ", os->zs.total_in,os->zs.total_out);
  return TRUE;
}
```

---

Structure definitions:

```
typedef struct {
  zrle_U8 *start; 
  zrle_U8 *ptr; //from start to ptr, we have data
  zrle_U8 *end;
} zrleBuffer;

typedef struct {
  zrleBuffer in; //input buffer
  zrleBuffer out; //output buffer

  z_stream   zs;
} zrleOutStream;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compressed stream you are providing, `inputStream[0..size-1]` is not complete.  The third call of `inflate()` has processed all of the input data you have provided, but it has not yet seen the end of the deflate stream.  If you check `avail_in` at that point, you will see that it's zero.

By the way, you don't need to set `data_type`.  That gets set by zlib.  It is just for information and can be ignored.

Comment: But the stream generated by deflate call is directly passed to inflate! Then how come the stream is incomplete?

Comment: You must be incorrectly collecting the output of deflate and determining its length.  You need to show that code.

Comment: That code is same as implemented in [zrleOutStreamFlush](http://libvncserver.sourceforge.net/doc/html/zrleoutstream_8c.html#a4f837e7e926e0827ec56775aae9e7d28) function. Actaully i am experimenting with zrle encoding/decoding part

Comment: Nowhere in there is `Z_FINISH` used to complete the stream.  You should look at this [annotated example for how to use zlib](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).

Comment: from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868211/z-buf-error-5-while-trying-to-decompress-zlib-data), i thought as i have complete stream, i had to use Z_FINISH.

Comment: You need to show how you are generating the deflate stream.

Comment: I have added the required part! Please tell anything obscure/unclear

Comment: So like I said, you are never giving `deflate()` the `Z_FINISH` flush parameter, so it is never finishing the compressed stream.

Comment: So when done with available input data, `Z_FINISH` should be used to end the stream, right?

Comment: As previously referenced, please read this [annotated example](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).  It will answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks Adler, i understood how zlib should be used! Thanks for such a great, portable, easeof use library!

Comment: @Adler,will below routine work?  starting deflate with `Z_NO_FLUSH` and loop till avail_in >0  then when last chunk(128kb) of data available, deflate with `Z_FINISH` ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes.  If you have to loop on the last chunk, i.e. if there is not enough output space to hold the result after the first call, then continue to call with `Z_FINISH` until you get all the output.